# General expression for $N$ qubit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-states

I know that if there are $N$ qubits then, there will be $2^N$ basis states. This is same as the dimension of the Hilbert space. Now I have seen here in discussion forms that there will be infinitely many system states possible.
But in the book Problems And Solutions In Quantum Computing And Quantum Information (4th Edition)
Book by W.-H Steeb and Yorick Hardy
In page no:34, they have this general expression for $N$-qubit system states.
$$\lvert\psi\rangle=\sum_{j_{1},j_{2},j_{3},...j_{N}=0}^{1}c_{j_{1},j_{2},j_{3},...j_{N}}\lvert j_{1}\rangle\otimes\lvert j_{2}\rangle\otimes...\otimes\lvert j_{N}\rangle
$$
They have also mentioned that only finite number of states are possible for an $N$ qubit system. But I am wondering we can select any value for the complex coefficient $c_i$ and how is this possible to have finite number of states!

Comment: I mean, they probably mean that there are a finite number of *basis* states, i.e., the dimension is finite, as you've already mentioned.  That's the only way I can make sense of this, because you're right that there are an infinite number of states, because the $c_i$'s can be any complex numbers, in general.  Otherwise, maybe there's some extra context that's missing?

Comment: @march But with the expression, it seems like finite number of states. Is the expression correct. Do you know of any other references about the infinite states.

Comment: How does that expression look like there are a finite number of states there? There are a finite number of basis elements $\lvert j_{1}\rangle\otimes\lvert j_{2}\rangle\otimes...\otimes\lvert j_{N}\rangle$, but the coefficients $c$ can be *any complex numbers*, which means that what you've written down parameterizes an infinite number of states. But I'm not sure why you need a reference. This is just standard linear algebra. For example, 2D spaces over the real numbers have an infinite number of states but only two basis vectors in a basis.